# AWS Cognito user-pool-based multi-tenancy - how to authorize users using JWT authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

I am wondering if it's possible to use AWS JWT Authorizer (HTTP API Gateway) to authenticate users from multiple Cognito user pools. Users across tenants cannot share user profiles in my case.
As I've checked REST API allows this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-authorizer.html#cfn-apigateway-authorizer-providerarns)

but HTTP API does not
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigatewayv2.CfnAuthorizer.html

Unfortunately I need to use HTTP API Gateway. What are yours suggestions here?